# How can we store firebase events offline and sync this events when device comes online bypassing 72 hours firebase offline sync limit?

Tags: ios, firebase

We are having an enterprise application which is used in regions where there is no internet for many days. I am using Firebase for analytics and I have enabled firebase persistent storage which helps to send the analytics events to firebase when the device comes online but the limitation is it only sends 72 hours data to Firebase analytics. So, I want firebase to get at least offline analytics data of the last 10 days. Can I achieve this by storing this analytics event in core data when the device is offline and send this event to firebase when the device is connected to the internet? Or is there any alternative way to achieve this? I only want to send the event name and timestamp of the event.